# Transfer an 8 mb double array to javascript

Tags: javascript, serialization, data-transfer

I have a 1024x1024 double matrix (i.e. 8mb array) which I need to use in a javascript app.

I found that using sylvester is quite useful for manipulating my matrix. My problem right now is simply to find an efficient way to load this array into a web page.

It seems quite tedious loading binary data into javascript. I thought using images as a mean of transfer but it seems quite tedious too...

For the record, it is a numpy ndarray, so I can play around with the format fairly easily from Python.

Thanks.

Edit: Right now I am dumping my raw array as a string and parsing it with the [Binary Parser by JSFromHell](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/binary-parser) but it's really, quite, slow...

Comment: Why are you sending all of the data to the client? Can't you just do the processing on the server and pass the results down via Ajax requests?

Comment: Due to the current technical configurations, I wouldn't have access to much more than a static web server.

Comment: You could maybe create a JSON array matrix of doubles from your raw array and then eval() it in one go? I would try align the data on the double byte boundaries so at least your string data doesnt contain any formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be the binary-capable XMLHttpRequest, see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data_using_JavaScript_typed_arrays. You could load the data directly into a `Float64Array` and it would be really fast. The downside: the spec wasn't finalized until recently (as you can see, Firefox 4/5 implements one approach while Firefox 6 will use another) and it is only implemented by Firefox and Chrome so far (with Chrome working the same as Firefox 6). So if performance is *really* important you could use this approach when possible (`XMLHttpRequest` has `responseType` or `mozResponseArrayBuffer` property) and fall back to the slow code otherwise. The hope would be that most people update their browsers soon and take the fast route.

Comment: I think this is going to be the best solution for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about json with compression using mod_gzip or the equivalent. Let the browser uncompress it.

Comment: I meant, to load in a web page, my problem is also passing from string  to array in an efficient manner.

Comment: Might work, but from the quick tests I just made, it's going to take from 110% to 150% the original space, depending on what string compression I use... On several Mb's the downloading time is probably going to be longer than the string to float conversion time. I'll update when I get to try it.

Comment: compressing a json array with gzip should shrink the size by 85%. i must be confused, sorry.

Comment: I meant, compared to raw binary data, using compressed json takes more size, since json is text (right? or is there a binary mode no one knows about?).

Answer (score 1):

Print it as a simple JSON, i.e. JS array:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

If you're printing this inside a `<script>` tag you can just pass it to variable:

```
var matrix = [...];
```

If it's loaded via AJAX pass it through `eval()`:

```
var matrix = eval( '(' + xhr.responseText + ')' );
```

I think nothing will convert a string to an array faster than browser's JS parser.

Comment: I agree, it looks like if you want the performance you are going to sacrifice some size. It may be best to stick to json and let it parse the doubles. Hopefully gzip compression can reduce the size somewhat.